# Launching C++ application by ignore dependency dll

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

My application contains lot of modules and one of the module is depending on some driver installation. To build, I have linked the static library. When we start the application, it will throw an error(dll was not found. reinstalling will fix) if the driver is not installed. The dll will be present in C:\Windows\System32 folder if the driver is installed. Is there a way to skip the dll dependency if it is not present on the system and continue with loading other modules.

Comment: You need to tell us more about that DLL. Is it used by the static library you mentioned?

Comment: Yes. It is used by the static library

Comment: So the static library is probably just an import library for the DLL. In that case you cannot prevent this message if the DLL doesn't exist. If you don't want the error message if the DLL doesn't exist, you cannot use an import library but you need to load the DLL via the `LoadLibrary` function and use `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: Another method would be to delay load the dll.

Comment: [Linker support for delay-loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls).